# Launching .exe file without pathing location c#

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics, c#-6.0

How I can launch exe file with c# code? 
So I have this :

```
Process.Start( @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Photoshop\Photoshop.exe");
```

But the path can be different in other machines. So is there any ideas to run .exe with different way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid hardcoding the path to the Program Files directory, but that still won't solve the problem. I might have installed Photoshop into a different directory (as indeed I have), or I might not have Photoshop installed at all.

Comment: Scan the Registry for the install path of Photoshop.

Comment: @Abion47 Not all programs store their install dir in the registry

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Most ones that have formal installation procedures do. Photoshop is one such example of those.

Comment: This question is quiet clear and narrow: voting to reopen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application"));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot run an exe file without knowing its location.

The "exception" is if the executable directory is in the PATH environment variable, which is why:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

works.

Comment: While this is technically true, there are other ways of getting the path besides hardcoding it.

Comment: @Abion47 Sure, there are the special folder classes etc, but that doesn't get past the basic problem of launching an exe regardless of where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly , the executable is in your reach, so just put it in the project directory and do not specify any path (the default is a relative path):

```
Process.Start("Photoshop.exe");
```

Comment: That seems very unlikely unless he is writing an app that is installed alongside photoshop

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz I think you cannot run all appa with your code. There are some apps like notepad you can run without path!